# aws s3 moving file is copying again instead of just renaming the path

Tags: aws-cli

I have a file in `s3` bucket

```
S3://mainbucket/fold1/fold2/file.txt
```

Now i want to move to the below path

```
S3://mainbucket/fold1/file.txt
```

I am doing

```
aws s3 mv S3://mainbucket/fold1/fold2/file.txt S3://mainbucket/fold1/file.txt
```

I see its copying the file instead of just moving.

I mean it will take time again.

Why its happening so.

Moving should be just changing the path.

Comment: It can be necessary to implement move as a copy followed by a delete. Maybe using the `--debug` option will help determine the issue.

Comment: What cli version do you use and what's the output of the command?